Springboot springdoc-openapi how to customize the swagger
Adding the dependency below gives access to the swagger ui.
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

But how to edit Swagger Title and etc using this dependency. In springfox it is possible using a docket bean. How is it possible in springdocs?
Trying to edit the swagger of Springdocs.

There are two to customize your openapi template.
There are in general two ways :
1- Through java code and creating a bean config :
First way, is by configure it through java code where you implement a bean, and write documentation about it, it would look like this but i don't recommend it:
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info()
                    .title("Custom API Title")
                    .description("Custom API Description")
                    .version("1.0.0")
                    .contact(new Contact()
                            .name("API Support")
                            .url("http://example.com/contact")
                            .email("support@example.com"))
                    .license(new License()
                            .name("Apache 2.0")
                            .url("http://springdoc.org")))
            .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                    .description("Full Documentation")
                    .url("http://example.com/docs"));
    }
}

2- yaml/properties config
Second way is to create template using springdoc-openapi and create either yml or properties file with documentation about your openapi, then when your application is running you can see the documentation.
It would look like this :
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
  info:
    title: Custom API Title
    description: Custom API Description
    version: 1.0.0
    contact:
      name: API Support
      url: http://example.com/contact
      email: support@example.com
    license:
      name: Apache 2.0
      url: http://springdoc.org
  external-docs:
    description: Full Documentation
    url: http://example.com/docs


Seems like sections info and external-docs can't be configured in application.yml, IntelliJ reports a lot of errors. BR

Annotate your controller class with @OpenAPIDefinition. For example:
@RequestMapping("/api")
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My App", description = "Some long and useful description",
                   version = "v1", license = @License(name = "Apache 2.0",
                   url = "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")))


This will look like this:


In the other hand, some thing like this could be use if you need more config (security,...)
    @OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                contact = @Contact(
                        name = "Testing api",
                        url = "https://github.com/abcde"
                ),
                description = "OpenApi for testing purpose",
                title = "Testing API"
        ),
        security = {
                @SecurityRequirement(
                        name = "bearerAuth"
                )
        }
)
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "bearerAuth",
        description = "JWT auth",
        scheme = "bearer",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER
)
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}

